# Normal Derivative of Scalar Curvature at a Minimal Surface

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, minimal-surfaces

Consider a Riemannian 3-manifold $M$ with boundary $\partial M$ with unit normal $n$, and mean curvature $H$. Consider the scalar curvature $R$. I'm interested in computing

$n^a \nabla_a R = \langle \nabla R, n \rangle$ at $\partial M$.

I'm wondering if there is some formula for this in terms of the mean curvature of the boundary, and I thought it best to ask here before trying to derive the formula. My great hope is that in the case $H=0$, we obtain $n^a \nabla_a R =0 $.

I have no idea if this is true, but it does turn out to be true in the case of the standard three dimensional slices of Schwarzchild space-time (trivially) and also of Reissner-Nordstrom (less trivially), so there is some hope.

Any help is appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a hope here, but a few more things need to be taken into the consideration. I don't know the exact answer, so let me just to contribute my twopence to the discussion.

In a slightly more general situation, where $M$ is an $n$-dimensional manifold with a Riemannian metric $g$, let us denote by $\nabla$ the Levi-Civita connection for the metric $g$, and $Riem$. $Ric$, and $R$ be the corresponding Riemannian, Ricci, and scalar curvatures. If $\overline{M} = \partial M$ is the boundary of $M$, and hence an embedded hypersurface, we have the induced Riemannian metric $\overline{g}$ on it, and the Levi-Civita connection of this metric, its Riemannian, Ricci, and scalar curvatures will be denoted as $\overline{\nabla}$,  $\overline{Riem}$,  $\overline{Ric}$, and  $\overline{R}$, respectively. Let $N$ be a choice of the unit vector along the boundary. We also need the notation $L$ for the second fundamental form, and $H$ for the mean curvature. (Since we are talking about derivatives, our consideration can be though as purely local).

In the notation as given above, there is a well-known consequence of the Gauss equation:
$$
\overline{R} = R - 2 Ric_{a b} N^a N^b + (n - 1)^2H^2 - |L|^2
$$
which holds along the hypersurface (boundary).

Now, the point is that the derivatives with respect to the ambient $\nabla$ do not make sense for most of the terms in this equation, unless you come up with a certain extension (slices, foliation, solutions of Cauchy equations... - ?).

Comment: I was thinking of using the Gauss equation, but it seemed like a lot of work so I wanted to see if there was a "known" answer somewhere. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @TheManWhoNeverSleeps It's my pleasure. This equation is usually referred to as the "twice contracted Gauss equation", and you can easily obtain it yourself, or lookup the details, for instance, in my thesis (see the link on my profile).